# How do I show an element using the below JQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.clicker').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.toggleClass('opened');

    var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100 ;
    $('#thiswillexpand').stop().animate({height: heights });
  });
});
```

By default I want #thiswillexpand to be hidden so I am going to use display:none; But when .clicker is clicked I want it to show and then expand as the script is supposed to.

**Question:**

How do I show #thiswillexpand when .clicker is clicked while still retaining whatever the script is doing?

Comment: What do you mean by 'retaining whatever the script is doing'?

Comment: Just add `$btn.show()`?

Comment: `$('#thiswillexpand').css('display', 'block');`

Comment: As you're animating the height, why don't you set the height to zero instead of the display to none ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to simply add a call to the `show()` function -

```
$('#thiswillexpand').show().stop().animate({height: heights });
```

The `show()` function is chainable, so you can just insert it before the calls to the other `stop` and `animate` functions.

Comment: Thanks @lix that worked but how do I hide when .clicker is clicked again?

Comment: @star - ahh.. Then I believe the function you are looking for is called [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Happy to help :)

Comment: I believe that will do what you want...yes.

Comment: Happy to help! Thank **you** for asking this question that helped me reach 20K :D

Comment: we should become friends then!